# How to return values from a dynamic SQL Stored Procedure to the Entity Framework?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, return-value, entity-framework-4

I have a Stored Procedure which executes some dynamic SQL. I want to use this Stored Procedure in entity framework 4, but when I try to create a complex type the procedure returns no columns. Is there any way I can force it to return my values and get the entity framework to receive them? Here is a much-simplified example of what I want to do:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_calculatesalary(@EmployeeId as int)
begin
    declare dynsql as varachar(500)
    @dynsql='Select @Salary=Salary,@UserName=Username from employee
            where EmployeeId='+cast(@EmployeeId as varchar)+ ''
    exec(@dynsql)
    select @Salary, @UserName
end
```

But this does not work. Please help me out. Basically, I want to use a Stored Procedure to execute dynamic SQL and return the values to the entity framework.

Comment: Why are you using dynamic SQL for this ?

Comment: Is it just to have a simple demo case, or is your dynamic statement really as simple as described above? In this case, you would not need dynamic SQL.

Comment: Well...this is just simple example..I am doing something complex....that's why using dynamic sql...i want to use it in entity framework..and get values..

Comment: Can you fool the Entity Framework by temporarily putting in dummy code that returns a result set of the format you want? Then alter the procedure definition with the actual code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Perhaps you could consider parameterized SQL, if you must do dynamic queries:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_calculatesalary(@EmployeeId as int)  
as 
begin   
    declare @dynsql varchar(500)   
    declare @params nvarchar(500)
    declare @salary money
    declare @username varchar(50)
    set @dynsql='Select @sal=Salary,@usernm=Username from employee where EmployeeId=@empID'   
    set @params='@empID int, @sal money OUTPUT, @usernm varchar(50) OUTPUT'
    exec sp_executesql @dynsql, @params, @empID=@EmployeeID, @sal=@salary OUTPUT, @usernm = @username OUTPUT
    SELECT @salary, @username
end
```

Comment: That is how I had it without scalar values...but entity framework didnt detect that it returned any columns....

Comment: Then perhaps you could post a little more info on why you need to do it dynamically.  Usually there's a way to do this without dynamic SQL.

Comment: I have multiple where clauses...that get appended to the main select...when i pass according parameters...So using dynamic sql to build those where clauses...but really all i want to know is to return values explicitly so that ef4 recognizes it...

Comment: In that case, the above edit should get you what you want.  I just like to highlight best practices to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks it worked...will keep in mind the practices..:)..
STACKOVERFLOW JUST ROCKS!!!

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_calculatesalary(@EmployeeId as int)   
AS
   DECLARE @dynsql VARCHAR(500)=' Salary,Username FROM employee WHERE EmployeeId=@empID'    
   EXEC sp_executesql @dynsql,'@empID INT',@empID=@EmployeeID
   SELECT 1 AS salary,2 AS username
```

**Believe me.
That is enough.**

Or you can simply create a complex type based on your query result , and then use collection of the complex type as your query result.

Comment: Thanks of all them this was the quickest and easiest. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

add following line at beginning of your SP

```
SET FMTONLY OFF
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below script this is working good.

```
BEGIN TRAN

DECLARE @Result varchar(max),@Table varchar(max),@Column varchar(max)

set @Column= 'CategoryName,CategoryID'
set @Table='Category'
set @Result= ' select ' + @Column + ' from '+@Table

exec(@Result)


ROLLBACK
```

Answer (score 1):

well, i think this is what you are looking for:

```
create procedure sp_calculatesalary
    @employeeId int
as
    declare @sql nvarchar(max);
    @sql='select salary, username from employee
            where employeeId=' + cast(@employeeId as nvarchar(10));

    declare @t table (salary float, username varchar(50));
    insert into @t exec(@sql);

    select salary, username from @t;
return
```

this will generate a public partial class sp_calculatesalary_Result in entity framework based DAL.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried giving aliases to your last Select:

```
select @Salary as Salary, @UserName as UserName
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if EF cannot recognize what your stored procedure must return then create your complex type ahead of time. You can create a complex type by right clicking any where on the model and and add a complex type. Next when you import your stored procedure, you can choose your complex  type from the dropdown.