# Preventing SQL Injection in non-executed SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-injection

I'm calling a web service and passing it a string of dynamically-generated SQL.  This string contains user input.  It is currently being built using simple string concatenation, and is therefore vulnerable to a SQL injection attack.  I cannot use the normal parameterized SQL solutions, because I'm not executing the command from my application.

My first attempt was to build a parameterized SqlCommand object.  However, there does not appear to be any way to extract the final SQL statement.  My second attempt was to use [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170.aspx), but that seems to have the same problem as my original code:  concatenating a SQL command together with user input.

So, how can I generate the SQL without resorting to writing my own input sanitization logic (i.e. `.Replace("'", "''")`?  Is there a built-in class or a good third-party library available?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to escape simple SQL queries in C# for SqlServer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403681/how-to-escape-simple-sql-queries-in-c-sharp-for-sqlserver)

Comment: Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx

Comment: No web service should be accepting and executing SQL Strings (unless its use is tightly restricted to users who are DBAs and Developers).  It is just a *really*, ***really*** bad idea.

Comment: I agree that passing SQL to a web service is quite bad.  Unfortunately, that is probably not something I can fix in the short term.  Also, both servers are inside my company's network, so man-in-the-middle attacks shouldn't be much of a concern.

Comment: Man-in-the_Middle attacks aren't the problem.  Techincally, neither is Sql Injection.  Hijacking your web-***client*** interface and then sending custom raw/unfiltered SQL commands is the *real* problem here.  Doing that and then using it to drive your SQL Server like a meat-puppet is so much easier than SQL-Injection it isn't even funny.  The good news is that since "both servers are in your company's network", there's probably nothing else that will get in their way.  See you in the headlines ...

Comment: The web service isn't publicly available.  It is called from a Windows service running internally, and connects to the database with an account that only has select privs.  The only connection to the outside world are small sets of user-entered strings, which I want to ensure are properly encoded (hence this question).  I don't see how your hyperbolic nightmare scenario applies to this situation.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand the question... how can you generate the SQL without resorting to writing my own input sanitization logic.  There are several sql injection mitigation techniques to consider using.
Some of these are security-based on the back-end and others are business and application development rules enforced by the database engine.

Back-End Security: Always apply the “Least Privilege” rule: set up low-privileged database accounts
for applications that access the DBMS.
Server Side Sanitation:  On the server side. validate user-supplied data – as well as any data obtained from a potentially unsafe sourceClient-side input validation can be
useful

Client-Side: Do not return SQL error messages to users as they contain information useful for
attackers, such as the query or details about the targeted tables or even their content.
This can be easily prevented in Java using exception handling.

Client-Side: Encode text input fields likely to contain problematic characters into an
alphanumeric version using a two-way function such as Base64.

Client-Side: Be proactive in writing the code to prevent SQL injection. Filter all input data via a 2-step process. First, apply white-list filtering at user
input collection (e.g., web forms): allow only field-relevant characters, string formats
and data types; restrict string length. Then, black-list filtering or escaping should be
applied in the data access layer before generating SQL queries: escape SQL metacharacters
and keywords/operators.

Client or middle-tier side.: Validate dynamically-generated database object names (e.g. table names) with strict white-list filtering.

Client-Side Avoid quoted/delimited identifiers as they significantly complicate all whitelisting,
black-listing and escaping efforts.

Development: Enforce process to have developers a safe API which will take care of security and avoid SQL Injection.  Do this instead of relying on developers to implement complex defensive coding techniques.

API: Develop an API or middel tier that analyzes the database schema at compile time
and writes code for a custom set of SQL query construction classes (which then
integrate into the IDE and are directly called by developers to build SQL queries).
The result is a tree-like structure based on a generic template, mapping the
possible variations of SQL queries according to tables and columns definition.
There are 3 main types of classes: SQL statements, table columns and where
conditions. These classes have strong-typed methods mapping the data types in the
database schema.  Attack surface is reduced.  The proposed API would not execute queries as you specified in your question, it only generates the SQL.  The proposed API would check data types against its mappings, upon input value submission. Second, the query would be pre-compiled by the
DBMS-specific driver using JDBC’s PreparedStatement interface with binded
variables. Any error in either step will prevent the query’s execution.

The proposed API design used by developers would address server-side validation , SQL error interception. Strong typing are directly enforced, while text input encoding and 2-step input validation are not needed , as dynamic input is injected through a separate protected data
channel (binded variables) via the PreparedStatement interface. Object names are not inputted by the user and are routinely validated. A low-privileged database account should however still be provided to the proposed API.

In the proposed API, Data input entry points do not need to be identified as protection is applied right before database interaction.  Segmented queries are fully supported; their
security is ensured as each query modification is validated by the API. White-filtering
and blacklisting are unnecessary as dynamic inputs are specified using binded variables.

In the proposed API, column lengths (e.g. for varchar fields) could be stored in the DB class (as
names and data types are) allowing the solution to perform bounds validation for
input data and therefore increase its protection level and overall accuracy.

Java-based prototypes of similar API designs are in progress and under current research efforts.